# Simple plane integration. I can’t spot my mistake. Help me please.

Tags: calculus

This is from a fluid mechanics book.
Here is the problem statement:
The area shown shaded is in a flow where the velocity field is given by $\vec{v} = 2x\hat{i} + 2y\hat{j} + \hat{k}$. Write a vector expression for an element of the shaded area. Evaluate the integral $\iint_A\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{A}$ and $\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) $ over the shaded area.
[The shaded area and my idea of scaling by a factor 5/4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSsrD.jpg)

After I checked the solution, I couldn't find my mistake. My guess is that if anything can go wrong, it have to be with the way I set up the infinitesimal area $d\vec{A}$.

Start with my approach first. My approaches is to find a normal vector pointing in a direction out of the page by using cross product.
$$\vec{A} = \vec{r}_{AB}\times\vec{r}_{CB}$$
From the picture, $\vec{r}_{AB} = -3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}$ and $\vec{r}_{CB} = 5\hat{k}$.
Substitute these in and I get
$$\vec{A} = (-3\hat{i}+4\hat{j})\times 5\hat{k} = 20\hat{i} + 15\hat{j}$$
and the unit normal vector $\hat{e}_A is$
$$\hat{e}_A = \frac{20\hat{i} + 15\hat{j}}{\sqrt{20^2+15^2}} = 0.8\hat{i} + 0.6\hat{j}$$

Next, I want to express the infinitesimal area $d\vec{A}$ in terms of $dy$ and $dz$  because I want to evaluate the integral from y=0 to y=4m and from z=0 to z=5m.
Since the side AB and DC has a length of 5m, but the projection of the two sides on yz-plane has a length of 4, so I think that the infinitesimal length must be $\frac54dy$ by trigonometry. The length of the other sides are still $dz$

So $$d\hat{A} = \hat{e}_A(\frac54dy)dz = \frac54(0.8\hat{i}+0.6\hat{j})dydz$$

Then. I evaluated the integral $\iint_A\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{A}$. I managed to get this part of the question right(Maybe it was a fluke).
$$\iint_A\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{A} = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4(2x\hat{i} + 2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})\cdot(0.8\hat{i}+0.6\hat{j})dydz$$
$$\iint_A\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{A} = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4(1.6x\hat{i} + 1.2y\hat{j})dydz$$
At this point, I substitute $x=-\frac34y+3$ as it can be obtained from the picture.
$$\iint_A\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{A} = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4(1.6(-\frac34y+3) + 1.2y)dydz$$
$$\iint_A\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{A} = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4(-1.2y+4.8 + 1.2y)dydz$$
$$\iint_A\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{A} = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^44.8dydz$$
$$\iint_A\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{A} = 120$$
As I mentioned before, this is correct (maybe by chance).

After that, I evaluated the integral $\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) $ ;however, this time my approach led me to incorrect result.
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4(2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})((2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})\cdot(0.8\hat{i}+0.6\hat{j}))dydz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4(2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})(1.6x+1.2y)dydz$$
Again, I substituted $x=-\frac34y+3$.So I have
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4(2(-\frac34y+3)\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})(1.6(-\frac34y+3)+1.2y)dydz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4((-\frac32y+6)\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})(-1.2y+4.8+1.2y)dydz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = (\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4((-\frac32y+6)\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})(4.8)dydz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = (4.8)(\frac54)\int_0^5\int_0^4((-\frac32y+6)\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})dydz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = (4.8)(\frac54)\int_0^5(12\hat{i}+16\hat{j}+4\hat{k})dz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = (4.8)(\frac54)(60\hat{i}+80\hat{j}+20\hat{k})dz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = 360\hat{i}+480\hat{j}+120\hat{k}dz$$
Now, please take a look at the solution. The solution came up with $$d\vec{A} = dydz\hat{i} + dxdz\hat{j}$$
I can see where this expression come from. The solution expresses $d\vec{A}$ as a sum of infinitesimal projected area on yz-plane which is $dydz\hat{i}$ and infinitesimal projected area on xz-plane which is $dxdz\hat{j}$.
Thus,
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = \iint_A(2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})((2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})\cdot(dydz\hat{i}+dxdz\hat{j}))$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = \iint_A(2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})((2x\,dydz+2y\,dxdz)$$
Since $x=-\frac34y+3$, then $dx=-\frac34dy$. Substitute $x$ and $dx$ in
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = \iint_A(2(-\frac34y+3)\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})((2(-\frac34y+3)dydz+2y(-\frac34dy)dz)$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = \iint_A((-\frac32y+6)\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})((-\frac32y+6)dydz+-\frac32y\,dydz)$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = \iint_A((-\frac32y+6)\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})((-\frac32y+6)dydz+-\frac32y\,dydz)$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = \int_0^5\int_0^4((-\frac32y+6)\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+\hat{k})(-3y+6)dydz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = \int_0^5\int_0^4(\frac92y^2-27y+36)\hat{i}+(-6y^2+12y)\hat{j}+(-3y+6)\hat{k}dydz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = \int_0^5 24\hat{i}-32\hat{j}dz$$
$$\iint_A \vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{A}) = 120\hat{i}-160\hat{j}$$

The initial set up of both method seem to make sense to me, but I don't know what is causing the difference between the two results. Please guide me.

Comment: Please type up the question so people do not have to click through.

Comment: @Ross Done. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: What are you told about $d\hat A$?  Why would a factor $\frac 54$ come in?  Why is it perpendicular to $\hat x$?

Comment: @Ross I found $d\hat{A}$ by taking cross product of side $-3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}$ and $5\hat{k}$. This gave me $\vec{A} = 20\hat{i} + 15\hat{j}$. I then calculate the unit vector, which is $\hat{e}_A = 0.8\hat{i} + 0.6\hat{j}$. The factor $\frac 54$ came in because the plane is slanted, and one side of the plane is the hypotenuse of a 3-4-5 right triangle, where the side of length 3 lies on x-axis and the side of length 4 lies on y-axis. So, I assume that for the infinitesimal area on the plane, one of the sides must be $\frac 54 dy$ by trigonometry and the another side is simply dz.

Comment: I am considering typing every line to clarify my idea, but I have to do it tomorrow because it is quite late here.

Comment: @RossMillikan Now I have updated my explanation, hopefully it is clear now.